# What are the kriyas Swahakaram and Vashatkaram means?

Tags: ramayana, rituals, vashishta

In Balagandam Sarkam 52 (I think), the following passage appears in Tamil:
[image]

Which when I translate:

> Then Vasishta said "Maharaj (addressing Vishwamithrar), I will not give Sabahalai in lieu of lakhs and lakhs or crores and crores of cows. I will  not give even silver is heaped liked mountain... (highlighted portion) Swahakaram, Vashatkaram - these two kriyas are preformed with Sabalai.

These Vashatkaram and Swahakaram kriyas are mentioned in this and being performed by Vasishta. What are these kriyas, what are its significance?

Comment: Swahakara refers to the sound swaha uttered in Yagnas, and Vashatkara is refers to the sound vashat uttered in Yagnas, just like omkara refers to the sound om.  (Sometimes it's used to refer to the deities of these sounds.)  And Kriya refers to action.  So I think the passage is just saying that cow Nandini is worshipping by uttering mantras that include swaha and vashat.

Comment: @Keshav The commentary to the Sloka on valmikiramayan.net says that Shabala is used for providing the required materials such as ghee and dung for the performance of Yajnas in additional to other magically procurable things.

Comment: @Surya OK, that makes sense - Vasishta is saying that it is with the help of Nandini that he can perform Yagnas in which Swaha and Vashat are uttered.